# applovin sdk problem with banner on unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, applovin

[image]
We Found that the problem occurs only in the banner. When the banner is initialized and starts to show or changes to another one. Freeze occurs in 100ms

We tried to rewrite the advertising initialization logic.
Left only the initialization and display of the banner
Did these actions in an empty scene

- There were no results after doing these steps.

Comment: does the same thing happen in an empty project?

Comment: did not try to create a clean project for this test. But in the end we tested applovin and everything is the same

Answer (score 0):

Did You seed logs on logcat ? try to update the max sdk to the latest.